# How can I use wildcards for audio Media in convo file in Botium?

Tags: botium-box

I have created a folder in specs/convo/audiodirectory, which contains some .wav files. Then I have a convo file which looks like this:

```
Utterance hit's relevant intent

#me
MEDIA audiodirectory/*.wav

#bot
INTENT RelevantIntent
```

My botium.json looks like this:

```
{
  "botium": {
    "Capabilities": {
      "PROJECTNAME": "Botium Project Lex",
      "CONTAINERMODE": "lex",
      "LEX_VERSION": "V2",
      "LEX_REGION": "[REDACTED]",
      "LEX_ACCESS_KEY_ID": "[REDACTED]",
      "LEX_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY": "[REDACTED]",
      "LEX_PROJECT_NAME": "[REDACTED]",
      "LEX_PROJECT_ALIAS": "[REDACTED]",
      "LEX_LOCALE": "en_GB",
      "LEX_ACCEPT": "audio/pcm",
      "USER_INPUTS": [
        {
          "ref": "MEDIA",
          "src": "MediaInput",
          "args": {
            "downloadMedia": true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

However, when I run botium-cli run, I receive an error:
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users[REDACTED]\botium-cli-test\specs\convo\audiodirectory*.wav'

I am following this part of the docs for reference: https://botium-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/05_botiumscript/index.html#media

Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I needed to use the botium-bindings node module. There is a post on the Botium forums with the answer here:

Answer found here https://forum.botium.ai/t/how-can-i-use-wildcards-for-audio-media-in-convo-file-in-botium/319